# How to judge the convergence of abstract sequence

Tags: summation

Given that $\{u_n\}$ is a monotonically increasing bounded sequence, now I want to judge whether the following sequence converges:

$$\begin{array}{c}
A.  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{u_{n}}{n}   &  B.  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{u_{n}} \\
C.  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}}\right)   & D.  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(u_{n+1}^{2}-u_{n}^{2}\right)
\end{array}$$

Since $\{u_n\}$ is an abstract sequence, I don't know how to use MMA to solve this problem.

Therefore, I use the following special case to verify the problem:

```
u[n_] := Sqrt[n/(n + 1)]

Sum[u[n]/n, {n, 1, Infinity}]
Sum[(-1)^n/u[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
Sum[1 - u[n]/u[n + 1], {n, 1, Infinity}]
Sum[u[n + 1]^2 - u[n]^2, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

However, MMA cannot judge whether `Sum[1 - u[n]/u[n + 1], {n, 1, Infinity}]` converges or not.

How can I judge the convergence of option `C` correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

u[n_] := Sqrt[n/(n + 1)]
```

[`SumConvergence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SumConvergence.html) indicates that the sum converges.

```
SumConvergence[1 - u[n]/u[n + 1], n]

(* True *)
```

Using a specific `Method`,

```
Assuming[n > 0, {#, SumConvergence[
      1 - u[n]/u[n + 1] // Simplify, n, Method -> #]} & /@
   {"RatioTest", 
    "RootTest", "RaabeTest", "IntegralTest"}] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have a way to deal with abstract sequences directly?

Comment: Since summands converge to zero faster than 1/n, the sum converges for n-> Infinity  `ser = Series[1 - u[n]/u[n + 1], {n, \[Infinity], 2}] // Normal ` yields  `1/(2 n^2) ` .